# add jvm for platform Desktop to the github project

Tags: android, kotlin, desktop, kotlin-multiplatform

i discovered this project on Github and would like to add JVM for the desktop view in the build.gradle i have already added everything. But now I am missing the execution.

***Here the GitHub Project: https://github.com/KSdesu06/ItemProject***
Can anybody add the Desktop jvm platform to this project ?

For this I first added the folder di similar to Android, and there the class AppModule:

```
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context
import org.company.app.db.AppDatabase
import org.company.app.db.DriverFactory
import org.company.app.repository.ItemRepository
import org.company.app.repository.ItemRepositoryImpl



actual class AppModule() {
    actual val repository: ItemRepository by lazy {
        ItemRepositoryImpl(
            database = AppDatabase(
                driver = DriverFactory(context).createDriver()
            )
        )
    }
}
```

and then I have a main.kt that looks like this:

```
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.window.Window
import androidx.compose.ui.window.application
import androidx.compose.ui.window.rememberWindowState
import java.awt.Dimension
import org.company.app.App
import org.company.app.di.AppModule


fun main() = application {
    Window(
        title = "ItemProject",
        state = rememberWindowState(width = 800.dp, height = 600.dp),
        onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication,
    ) {
        window.minimumSize = Dimension(350, 600)
        App(appModule = AppModule())
    }
}
```

My problem is *:composeApp/src/jvmMain/kotlin/org/company/app/di/AppModule.kt:3:33
Symbol is declared in module 'jdk.compiler' which does not export package 'com.sun.tools.javac.util'*

but I think that the call of the function in main.kt with App(appModule = AppModule()) can be wrong but I don't know.

This is what the Android APp.android.kt looks like and it works:

```
import android.app.Application
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import org.company.app.di.AppModule

class AndroidApp : Application() {
    companion object {
        lateinit var INSTANCE: AndroidApp
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        INSTANCE = this
    }
}

class AppActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            App(appModule = AppModule(LocalContext.current.applicationContext))
        }
    }
}
```